mariadb npm package database keeps timing out even if it's under no load
I have a query function that takes an sql and executes it, like this:
import mariadb, { QueryOptions } from "mariadb";

const pool = mariadb.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    acquireTimeout: 30000,
    connectTimeout: 10000,
    idleTimeout: 60000,
});

export async function query(sql: string | QueryOptions, values?: Array<unknown>) {
    let conn;
    try {
        console.log("Attempting to get a connection from the pool...");
        conn = await pool.getConnection();
        console.log(`Connection acquired. Active connections: ${pool.activeConnections()}, Idle connections: ${pool.idleConnections()}`);

        console.log("Executing query...");
        const rows = await conn.query(sql, values);

        console.log("Query executed successfully:", rows);
        return rows;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error executing query:", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (conn) {
            console.log("Releasing connection back to the pool...");
            await conn.release();
            console.log(`Connection released. Active connections: ${pool.activeConnections()}, Idle connections: ${pool.idleConnections()}`);
        }
    }
}

process.on("SIGINT", async () => {
    console.log("Closing database pool...");
    await pool.end();
    process.exit(0);
});

However, it just kills itself and throws a timeout error every few minutes. Can anyone help me?

Does this happen for all queries, even simple ones? It the query is complex, it may be very slow. What happens if you try the same query by hand with the CLI client?

it happens with the simplest of queries, like just a select query with nothing special. If I try to connect to the CLI to execute the queries, it gives me a "too many connections" error, but I release the connections after querying, so idk what's happening there.

You need to use SHOW PROCESSLIST to see what all those other connections are.

It's creating a LOT of processes https://privatebin.net/?7b48638e4078389c#7yvyQaPkWsZUTdVHMmP92oaAwGjuRshGrPKpHUE4PpfY

Looks like you have something that isn't closing its connection when it's done.

I mean yes it's doing exactly that, but I have the connection released at the end of the function, so why would it not close?

There's probably something other than this script accessing the DB.

I don't think so, when I close the project, all the connections disappear

Do you see the log Connection released log messages?

yeah I do see it

I was going to recommend using conn.destroy() instead of conn.release(). But the default connectionLimit is only 10, so I don't see how the connection pool could be creating hundreds of connections even if you don't destroy them.

yeah it was weird asf, I "solved" it by recreating the backend in Rust and just sending fetch requests, which is arguably slower but at least it doesn't crash my database, or maybe I was just doing the wrong things..
